# AlamoFire isn't sending the params to PHP

Tags: ios, alamofire

Here is my AlamoFire code

```
let parameters = ["test": "true"]

Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: parameters ,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {
response in
  switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    print(response)
                    break
                case .failure(let error):

                    print(error)
                }
}
```

An example of my PHP code is here.
I always get the error. Is it my PHP or AlamoFire?

```
if($_POST['test'] == 'true'){
    $json = json_encode(array(
        "ack" => "success",
        "message" => "good"
    ));
      echo $json;
} else {
    $json = json_encode(array(
        "ack" => "error",
        "message" => "not good"
    ));
      echo $json;
}
```

Comment: Your URL protocol is HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: @RagenDazs its https

Comment: Paste your request reponse from Xcode console, let we see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change your encoding for URLEncoding.default

```
AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: p, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON {
```

Comment: Could you share this URL? Or if you prefer you can use Postman to debug your PHP and apart the problem from swift

Comment: i had a typo in my params. this fixed it the overall issue though. thanks